# When I don't change my pic its deleted

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am a new developer. I have created a plugin for data insert WP dashboard. I am trying to form submit with Ajax in WordPress. When I change the pic its updated successfully, but when I not change pic its deleted. Why? There is my code.

**form:**

```
<form id="ajax_form_update"  method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table class='wp-list-table widefat fixed'>
        <tr><th></th><td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/></td></tr>
        <tr><th>Name</th><td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/></td></tr>
        <tr><th>Code</th><td><input type="text" name="code" value="<?php echo $code; ?>"/></td></tr>
        <tr><th>Image</th><td ><img id="blah" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <?php echo  $photo;?> " width="100" height="100" /> </td></tr>
        <tr><th></th><td><input  type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" name="photo"   class="ss-field-width" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type='submit' name="submit" value='Save' class='button'> &nbsp;&nbsp;
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
function ajaxupdate() {
    global $wpdb;
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $code = $_POST["code"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $imagesss = ($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"]);
    $bin_string = file_get_contents("$imagesss");
    $aencode1 = base64_encode($bin_string);
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "school";
    //update
    $result = $wpdb->update(
                $table_name, //table
                array('code' => $code, 'name' => $name,'image_name'=>$aencode1 ), //data
                    array('id' => $id) //where
                );
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxupdate', 'ajaxupdate' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxupdate', 'ajaxupdate');
```

**AJAX**

```
jQuery("#ajax_form_update").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action
    var post_url = jQuery(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var request_method = jQuery(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
    var form_data = new FormData(this); //Creates new FormData object
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/mywp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ajaxupdate",  
        type: request_method,
        data : form_data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success:function(data){  
            alert ('Data Updated');
            //location.reload();
         },
    });
});
```

Comment: When you dont change the pic are you getting blank value in db column for the corresponding image?

Comment: Yes, I saw that, what is the solution?

Comment: Every time your form is submitted you are getting image , when the image is changed you are getting image name but when its not you are getting blank value which then gets updated in your db. Before saving image just check if it's empty or not, if it's empty do not update image column in db.

Comment: I need solution brother,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code :

```
if(!empty(imagesss)){
    //update
            $result = $wpdb->update(
                        $table_name, //table
                        array('code' => $code, 'name' => $name,'image_name'=>$aencode1 ), //data
                        array('id' => $id) //where

                );
    } else {
    //update
            $result = $wpdb->update(
                        $table_name, //table
                        array('code' => $code, 'name' => $name), //data
                        array('id' => $id) //where

                );
    }
```